# How to avoid hardcoded passwords on Apache httpd config file

Tags: passwords, apache-http-server, ldap

I'm using an Apache Proxy with LDAP modules for authentication management. But I don't want to hardcode the password of the LDAP service user to query the domain.

I have already used other applications that work with secure storage or wallets of passwords that only the service can query to resolve `${wallet_key_name}` references.

Does something similar exist for Apache httpd?

Comment: There is an `Include` directive so you can include a file that only contains the secret. Perhaps there is a specific feature for this situation, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Is your Apache httpd running on Linux?

Comment: Windows unfortunately